# Stream current log to storage folder

Tags: laravel

I am running my `Laravel 7` application for testing purposes on a shared host.

My `logging.php` configuration looks like the following:

```
<?php

use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\SyslogUdpHandler;

return [

    'default' => env('LOG_CHANNEL', 'single'),

    'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['daily'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'error',
        ],

        'daily' => [
            'driver' => 'daily',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => 'debug',
            'days' => 14,
        ],

        'slack' => [
            'driver' => 'slack',
            'url' => env('LOG_SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL'),
            'username' => 'Laravel Log',
            'emoji' => ':boom:',
            'level' => 'critical',
        ],

        'papertrail' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'level' => 'debug',
            'handler' => SyslogUdpHandler::class,
            'handler_with' => [
                'host' => env('PAPERTRAIL_URL'),
                'port' => env('PAPERTRAIL_PORT'),
            ],
        ],

        'stderr' => [
            'driver' => 'monolog',
            'handler' => StreamHandler::class,
            'formatter' => env('LOG_STDERR_FORMATTER'),
            'with' => [
                'stream' => 'php://stderr',
            ],
        ],

        'syslog' => [
            'driver' => 'syslog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],

        'errorlog' => [
            'driver' => 'errorlog',
            'level' => 'debug',
        ],
    ],

];
```

I only get the log file from the day before in my `storage` folder. However, I would like to get the logs that are created when the application runs, like a log stream.

Any suggestions how to do this?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

so far, I am new to logs too. The two lines below can be added to any controller

```
use Log; #on top along with the other 'use' statements
```

this 2nd line would be inserted as needed:

```
Log::info('File: '. __FILE__. ' This would get logged on file: storage/laravel.log');
```

The result is appended onto laravel.log and would be similar to:

```
[2020-07-11 05:08:38] local.INFO: File: C:\<someFolders>\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Route.php This would get logged on file: storage/laravel.log
```

'hope it helps.